# Missing values in two tables

Tags: php

I have  two php  table

table A  has a column of amount with 21,22,23,23,24,25

table B has a column of amount with  21,22,23,25

I want a code that will print out the missing values that are in table a and not in b .

ie 23,24

Comment: Are those values in an array, or are they static HTML? By the way what have you already tried?

Comment: what exactly is a PHP table?

Comment: table with a column amount , the values are inside the table

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but is this the kind of thing you are after?

```
select * from `tableA` where `colname` not in ( select `colname` from `tableB` )
```

Comment: I think you have the tables backward? "All values in tableA that aren't in tableB".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tb1` WHERE `tb1`.`value` NOT IN (SELECT `col` FROM `tb2`)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.